# Adding values to SharedPreferences from a Custom ListViewAdapter

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to add values to the SharedPreferences from a list, the idea is when a user click on a button the list item is added to the favorites page, however I'm not able to do so, I believe the problem is because I'm using a custom ListViewAdapter, this listview allows me to swipe a list item to the left so that it shows the button. [Like so](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0sYkdWQO6iJX2NCbFlOOGR1bk0)
I can't put the SharedPreferences to work in this class, this is what I have:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseSwipeAdapter {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> array = TodasAsCategorias.getListaCategorias();
    String Designacao, K_PRODUTO;
    public static final String favoritos = "favoritos";

    private Context mContext;

    public ListViewAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getSwipeLayoutResourceId(int position) {
        return R.id.swipe;
    }

    @Override
    public View generateView(final int position, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item_cat, null);
        SwipeLayout swipeLayout = (SwipeLayout) v.findViewById(getSwipeLayoutResourceId(position));
        v.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnFav).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Designacao = (array.get(position)).get("Designacao");
                K_PRODUTO = (array.get(position)).get("K_PRODUTO");
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Adicionado aos favoritos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(favoritos, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("Designacao", Designacao);
                editor.apply();

            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    /*....*/
}
```

It keeps giving me the same errors, Cannot resolve method 'getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, ?)' and Cannot resolve symbol 'MODE_PRIVATE'

Really need help here, can't find anything in the web to help me :/

Comment: put onClick method under generate view

Comment: @BasilBattikhi How so? Out of the generate view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getSharedPreferences() needs a context to be accessed.

```
mContext.getSharedPreferences
```

try

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences(favoritos, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to do

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences(favoritos, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
```